# Hide all php extensions and GET variables (if exists)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to hide all `.php` extensions from the URL, and if there are GET variables, I need to hide them too.

Ex.:

- `www.mysite.com/panel/employees.php` to `www.mysite.com/panel/employees`
- `www.mysite.com/panel/employees.php?c=1` to `www.mysite.com/panel/employees/1`
- `www.mysite.com/adm/tables.php` to `www.mysite.com/adm/tables`
- `www.mysite.com/adm/tables.php?c=3` to `www.mysite.com/adm/tables/3`
- And more URL's with the same idea

So I came up with the following code (with some research)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

It works fine, however, it hides only the extension and not the variable (Ex.: `www.mysite.com/panel/employees.php?c=1` to `www.mysite.com/panel/employees?c=1`).

I tried to make changes to the above code, however, since I'm new to `.htaccess`, I did not succeed. So if anyone can help me explain how to do it, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need additional set of rules to handle query parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+)\.php\?c=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?c=$2 [END,QSA]
```

Comment: Work's fine if I access `www.mysite.com/employees.php?c=1` (rewrite to `employees/1`) and if I access `www.mysite.com/employees.php` rewrite to `employees` but I've a 404 error (when GET var does not exist)

Comment: All that do not have GET variables, like `www.mysite.com/employees.php`, `www.mysite.com/tables.php`, etc. The extension is removed, but returns 
404 error

Comment: So directly entering `www.mysite.com/employees` in browser also gives 404? btw that rule is unchanged from your question

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it returns error 404 when accessing the URL without variables

Comment: It was only working to remove the extension, but it didn't rewrite the GET variables

Comment: Both are at the root. If I remove the `.htaccess` everything works perfectly (but with extensions and GET vars, obviously) - "If you rollback my suggested rules and keep only your code shown in question and enter...", yes, it works!

Comment: Now the error is reversed. If I enter `www.mysite.com/employees` it works, but if I enter `www.mysite.com/employees/1` I've a 404 error

Comment: Again works fine if I access `www.mysite.com/employees.php?c=1` (rewrite to `employees/1` without errors). If I access `www.mysite.com/employees.php` rewrite to `employees` and I've a 404 error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151431/discussion-between-anubhava-and-igor).